# Batch rotate images by 180 degrees from the command-line

Tags: images

I'd like to rotate a series of images by 180 degrees clockwise from the command-line in a way I can write into a shell script to make things faster and more convenient. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ImageMagic tool convert:

```
convert foto.jpg -rotate 180 newfoto.jpg
```

Howto was taken from here:

https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/82423/how-do-i-rotate-a-lot-of-digital-photos-by-180-degrees-in-one-operation/82461